# Get File Contents OneDrive Business connector error when submitting data from Microsoft Forms to SharePoint List via Power Automate

Tags: error, outlook, attachments, onedrive-for-business, microsoft-forms

Goal: Have Microsoft Forms data including attachments be automatically submitted into SharePoint List and email the correct party and include the approval attachment from Microsoft Forms.

This was working just fine for me until we had to Migrate this flow from our test environment into our Prod environment which is also a shared group. It no longer works and produces an error at the Get File Content action and says the resource could not be found (404 error) even though I still have full access to the OneDrive and see it syncing correctly. It does create the item on the SP list just fine but without the attachment. The flow works all the way until it hits the Get File Content. We need to use the get file content as the team that will be submitting these credit request will not be using the same file path for their attachments.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]